# How can i write unit test for an API call with useSWR?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a pokemon app with using `nextjs`. I am making an API request using the pokemon name I got from the url and according to the returned response, I print `loading`, `pokemon not found` and `pokemon` information. I'm new to writing unit tests and I can't understand the logic in writing the test of the API request I'm making. Can you help me?

[pokemon].tsx

```
export default function PokemonDetailsPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pokemonName = router.query.pokemon?.toString() || "";

  const { pokemon, pokemonLoading } = usePokemon(pokemonName);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        {pokemon && <title>{`${pokemon.name} + Nextjs PokeDex`}</title>}
      </Head>
      <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <p>
          <Link href="/" className="link-light">
            ← PokeDex
          </Link>
        </p>
        {pokemonLoading && <Spinner animation="grow" />}
        {pokemon === null && <p>Pokemon not found</p>}
        {pokemon && (
          <>
            <h1 className="text-center text-capitalize">{pokemon.name}</h1>
            <Image
              src={pokemon.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default}
              alt={"Pokemon: " + pokemon.name}
              width={400}
              height={400}
            />
            <div className="d-inline-block mt-2">
              <div>
                <strong>Types:</strong>{" "}
                {pokemon.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(", ")}
              </div>
              <div>
                <strong>Height:</strong> {pokemon.height * 10} cm
              </div>
              <div>
                <strong>Weight:</strong> {pokemon.weight / 10} kg
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

usePokemon Custom Hook

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import * as PokemonApi from "@/network/pokemon-api";
import { AxiosError } from "axios";

export default function usePokemon(name: string) {
  const { data, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR(name, async () => {
    try {
      return await PokemonApi.getPokemon(name);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError && error.response?.status === 404) {
        return null;
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  });

  return {
    pokemon: data,
    pokemonLoading: isLoading,
  };
}
```